# How to implement hateoas in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I need to migrate our spring boot application to Quarkus. Facing the issue of how to implement the hateoas in Quarkus. Any suggestions are welcome.

Spring boot code:

```
import org.springframework.hateoas.Link;
import org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder;

    public String getHref(ProductOfferApiRequest productOfferApiRequest) {
        Link link = ControllerLinkBuilder
                .linkTo(ProductOfferingController.class)
                .slash("getProductOrderService")
                .slash(productOfferApiRequest.getRequestHeader().getOrderID())
                .slash(productOfferApiRequest.getRequestHeader().getSessionID())
                .withSelfRel();
        return link.getHref();
        return null;
```

Looking similar solution in Quarkus.

Answer (score 4):

For Quarkus RESTEASY Reactive extension, you can also use the dependency "quarkus-resteasy-reactive-links" which gives you support for Web links (hateoas). See [the official documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#web-links-support) about this dependency.

If what you're looking for, it's to programmatically access the generated links, then you would need to inject the RestLinksProvider as:

```
@Inject
RestLinksProvider linksProvider;
```

And then use the `getTypeLinks(class)` or `getInstanceLinks(instance)` to search for the links.

Instead, if what you're looking for, it's to manually generate the links yourself (you want to use the provided `@InjectRestLinks` and `@RestLink` annotations as described in the documentation), then you can build the links yourself as follows:

```
Response response = Response.ok()
            .header("Link", Link.fromUri(...).build())
            .build();
```

Note that the `Link` class is a builder with lots of options.

I hope it helps!